# Is the nilpotent exponent of the Jacobson radical of algebra a Morita equivalent invariant？

Tags: ring-theory, representation-theory, morita-equivalence

I have known that two rings A and B are said to be Morita equivalent if the left module categories mod A and mod B are equivalent. Many properties of module category are Morita equivalent invariant, and we know ideal of A and B are one to one corespondents. I want to know is the nilpotent exponent of Jacobson radical of ring a Morita equivalent invariant？I think it is right for left Artin rings. Firstly, we have an equivalence functor F:mod A $\to$ mod B, for an A-module M, we have $rad^i M=\mathfrak{r}^i M$, where $\mathfrak{r}$ is the Jacobson radical of $A$. Secondly, we note that the nilpotent exponent of Jacobson radical is the maximum of radical length of $M$, for each A-module $M$. Finally, I think
$F$ preserve the length of radical sequence of $M$, i.e. $rl_A M=rl_B F(M)$ . Therefore, the nilpotent exponent of Jacobson radical of left artin rings a Morita equivalent invariant. But I’m not sure it is right, and I want to know is it true for arbitrary ring.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Can you define what a nilpotent exponent is?

Comment: Sorry, I want to say that nilpotent exponent of Jocabson radical of ring.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The natural correspondence between the ideals of two Morita equivalent rings $R$ and $S$ preserves products of ideals, takes $\operatorname{rad}R$ to $\operatorname{rad}S$, and of course takes the zero ideal to the zero ideal.

So $\operatorname{rad}^nR=0$ if and only if $\operatorname{rad}^nS=0$.

You can find proofs of the necessary results in, for example, Proposition 18.44 and Corollary 18.50 of

*Lam, T. Y.*, [**Lectures on modules and rings**](https://mathoverflow.net/a/299700), Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 189. New York, NY: Springer. xxiii, 557 p. (1999). [ZBL0911.16001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0911.16001).